# Configure Symfony Route to match database fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, routes, yaml

I'm new to Symfony2 and am learning by making a concert finder application.

Currently I have a couple of yaml routes:

```
london_hello_bands:
  path:     /hello/{band}
  defaults: { _controller: LondonHelloBundle:Hello:band }

london_hello_multiple:
  path:     /hello/{venue}/{band}
  defaults: { _controller: LondonHelloBundle:Hello:more }
```

These are mapped to the following Actions within my HelloController:

```
public function bandAction($band)
{
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository('LondonHelloBundle:Gig');

$bandinfo = $repository->findByArtist($band);

    return $this->render(
        'LondonHelloBundle:Hello:band.html.twig',
        array('band'=>$bandinfo)
        );
}


public function moreAction($venue, $band)
 {
  $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository('LondonHelloBundle:Gig');
  $venueinfo = $repository->findBy(
       array('venueName'=>$venue, 'artist'=>$band)
 );

     return $this->render(
      'LondonHelloBundle:Hello:venue.html.twig',
      array('venues'=>$venueinfo)
      );
}
```

This seems to all work fine and I can use Doctrine to pull out all the info about a band from the database at /hello/blur (for example) and I can show all the info about a particular band at a particular venue at hello/02/blur (for example - 02 is the name of an arena in the UK).

However I also want to be able to show all the bands playing a particular venue at a URL like hello/02, however this conflicts with my first route:

```
path:     /hello/{band}
```

Is there a way I can associate a route with a particular field in the database (I was thinking maybe something like conditions https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-expressions)? or do I just have to live with this and put some logic in the Twig template to handle things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can use some rules to distinguish between band and venue names (eg. band names start with lowercase, venues uppercase) you have to use logic in your controller (not template!).

```
public function bandOrVenueAction($band_or_venue)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository('LondonHelloBundle:Gig');

    $bandinfo = $repository->findByArtist($band_or_venue);

    if(empty($bandinfo) === false) {

        return $this->render(
            'LondonHelloBundle:Hello:band.html.twig',
            array('band'=>$bandinfo)
            );
    }

    $venueinfo = $repository->findByArtist($band_or_venue);

    if(empty($venueinfo) === false) {

        return $this->render(
            'LondonHelloBundle:Hello:venue.html.twig',
            array('venueinfo'=>$venueinfo)
            );
    }

    // display 404
}
```

Comment: OK thanks. So essentially I have to check the db to see if there is a band that matches the string in the URL, if there is render the correct template. If there isn't check if there's a venue that matches the string - if there is render the correct template else handle the error.  I guess then I just have to hope that there are no bands and venues that share the same name!

Comment: Better add another field, `slug`, that will hold the url for venues and bands. You can't rely there are not venues with the same name, also unknown bands can have the same name. Use validator to check if the url exists.